# How to delay Primefaces AjaxStatus on JSF?

Tags: ajax, jsf, primefaces

How to add a delay (300ms for example) on when the Primefaces' AjaxStatus would show. Right now it shows always immediately when there's an Ajax request pending. This is troublesome for example on "onkeyUp" events when each key stroke brings the loading dialog up for a split second.

Here's my AjaxStatus loading indicator component:

```
<p:ajaxStatus id="startAjax" onstart="PF('start').show();" oncomplete="PF('start').hide();" >
</p:ajaxStatus>

<p:dialog widgetVar="start" showHeader="false" resizable="false">
    <h:graphicImage value="#{resource['/images/loading.gif']}"></h:graphicImage>
</p:dialog>
```

Comment: you can use primefaces extension `<pe:timer>` and call ajaxStatus from timer or `onShow` property is available in `<p:dialog>` from there call timer which will not do anything just wait and then control will come back to dialog and ajaxStatus will show.

Comment: @techipank, it seems that pe:timer is deprecated. I addes Primefaces Extensions to maven dependencies and the namespace xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions" and pe: only offers timeline and timepicker components. There's no timer. Perhaps <p:poll> would be suitable as well

Comment: With your own Javascript-function: `onstart="myStart('start')"` and in `function myStart(pfo) {` you use `window.setTimeout()` to call `PF(pfo).show()`

Comment: @holger is right. All plain javascript. Nothing ajax, jsf or PrimeFaces related

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to wrap your PF('start').start() with a function which will call it with a delay. Also, the onComplete handler should check if you have pending status to show and cancel them. This is to avoid the case where ajax finished before status displayed.

Code should be something like this (not tested)

```
<p:ajaxStatus id = "startAjax" onstart = "startHandler();" oncomplete = "endHandler();"/>
    <script>
        var ajaxInProgress;
        function startHandler() {
            ajaxInProgress = setTimeout(function () {
                if(ajaxInProgress){
                   PF('start').show();
                }
            }, 3000);
        }
        function endHandler() {
            clearTimeout(ajaxInProgress);
            PF('start').hide();
            ajaxInProgress = null;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and check your answer if it's correct.

Comment: Yes it works. 400 milliseconds seemed to be the sweet spot for my application.

Answer (score 1):

I submitted a PR that this delay attribute will be native in PF 7.1+.

https://github.com/primefaces/primefaces/pull/5138

Thanks for the suggestion!